# Using multiple EntityManager with Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 2, Spring Data REST, Spring HATEOAS, Spring JPA, Hibernate.
My project worked fine before last change where I added a new EntityManager.

This is the start class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"cloud.myapp", "management"})
public class OptixServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

this is the first entityManager:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "cloud.myapp.server.repositories",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
)
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
                                                                       CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("myapp.U");
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("cloud.myapp.server");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", env.getProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect.storage_engine", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect.storage_engine"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", env.getProperty("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy"));

        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", env.getProperty("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size"));
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", env.getProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"));
        properties.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", env.getProperty("hibernate.max_fetch_depth"));
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.time_zone", env.getProperty("hibernate.jdbc.time_zone"));
        properties.put("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", env.getProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers"));
        properties.put("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions"));

        // Interceptor for Agents
        // properties.put("hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", agentInterceptor());
//        properties.put("hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", hibernateInterceptor());
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        em.afterPropertiesSet();

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException,
            InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriver(((Driver) Class.forName(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.driver-class-name")).getDeclaredConstructor()
                .newInstance(null)));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
                                                         CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                entityManagerFactory(multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl).getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

and this is the additional one:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:management.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "cloud.management.server.repositories",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "managementEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "managementTransactionManager"
)
@Log4j2
public class ManagementDBConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "managementEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean managementEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(managementDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("cloud.management.server.model");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("management.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("management.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("management.jpa.hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", env.getProperty("management.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size"));
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", env.getProperty("management.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"));
        properties.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", env.getProperty("management.jpa.hibernate.max_fetch_depth"));
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", env.getProperty("management.jpa.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.time_zone", env.getProperty("management.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone"));
        properties.put("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", env.getProperty("management.jpa.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers"));
        properties.put("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions", env.getProperty("management.jpa.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions"));


        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource managementDataSource() {
        return createDataSource();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager managementTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(managementEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private DataSource createDataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikari = new HikariConfig();

        hikari.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("management.datasource.url"));
        hikari.setUsername(env.getProperty("management.datasource.username"));
        hikari.setPassword(env.getProperty("management.datasource.password"));

        // MySQL optimizations, see
        // https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration
        String keyPrefix = "management.hikari.";
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "cachePrepStmts"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "prepStmtCacheSize"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "prepStmtCacheSqlLimit"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "useServerPrepStmts"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("useLocalSessionState", env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "useLocalSessionState"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("rewriteBatchedStatements", env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "rewriteBatchedStatements"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("cacheResultSetMetadata", env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "cacheResultSetMetadata"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("cacheServerConfiguration", env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "cacheServerConfiguration"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("elideSetAutoCommits", env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "elideSetAutoCommits"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("maintainTimeStats", env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "maintainTimeStats"));
        hikari.setMinimumIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "minimumIdle")));
        hikari.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "maximumPoolSize")));
        hikari.setIdleTimeout(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "idleTimeout")));
        String connectionPoolName = "JPAHikari_management";

        hikari.setPoolName(connectionPoolName);
        // mysql wait_timeout 600seconds
        hikari.setMaxLifetime(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "maxLifetime")));
        hikari.setLeakDetectionThreshold(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty(keyPrefix + "leakDetectionThreshold")));

        DataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikari);

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

The first entityManager has to deal with multi tenants, so I implemented MultiTenantConnectionProvider:

```
@Component
@Log4j2
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3193007611085791247L;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionPoolManager connectionPoolManager;

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return connectionPoolManager.getConnection(TenantContext.TENANT_DEFAULT);
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantId) throws SQLException {
        // log.info("getConnection " + tenantId);
        Connection connection = connectionPoolManager.getConnection(tenantId);

        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantId, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        log.info("releaseConnection " + tenantId);
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

and this is my ConnectionPoolManager:

```
@Component
@Profile({"prod"})
@Log4j2
public class ConnectionPoolManagerImpl implements ConnectionPoolManager {

    @Autowired
    private DataSourceCache dataSourceCache;

    @Autowired
    private TenantDbCache tenantDbCache;

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseInstanceRepository databaseInstanceRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncrypt passwordEncrypt;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource primaryDataSource;



    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(@NotNull String tenantId) {
        //use second DB repository, create(or reuse) a datasource and from that get the connection
    }


}
```

When I start the project I get this exception:

```
08/06/2019 15:40:57,071 ERROR main SpringApplication:858 - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorySearchController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Daniele/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/3.1.8.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositorySearchController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.RepositoryEntityLinks]: Factory method 'entityLinks' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class cloud.myapp.server.model.accounting.documents.rows.DocumentRow!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:843) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at cloud.myapp.server.OptixServerApplication.main(OptixServerApplication.java:38) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.RepositoryEntityLinks]: Factory method 'entityLinks' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class cloud.myapp.server.model.accounting.documents.rows.DocumentRow!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.RepositoryEntityLinks]: Factory method 'entityLinks' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class cloud.myapp.server.model.accounting.documents.rows.DocumentRow!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class cloud.myapp.server.model.accounting.documents.rows.DocumentRow!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:394) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at
```

I got the sense of the message but I don't see how I can tell Spring Data REST how to use the right entityManager.
Any hint would be really appreciated.

======== EDIT =========

Additional info: removing `DatabaseInstanceRepository` from `ConnectionPoolManagerImpl` the project starts. It seems I'm not able to use a repositories of the second DB in the `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` of the first one.